# How to configure jenkins to choose the schema by default?

Tags: oracle, jenkins

I get the a query file and commit it but I have to choose the schema before it, to not get the following error; do you have any idea how to do it?

Thanks for your interest.

```
INSERT INTO LEAD_ACTV_CONFIG (
             *
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: How are you connecting to DB in the first place?

Comment: with the connection method and there is not any problem with the connection. just I need to configure the jenkins to know the schema

Comment: Using a plugin?? Or in the script itself you are connecting? Your question didn't mention it.

Comment: in the script itself is connecting

Comment: which script?? Groovy??? Ruby???

Comment: in sql statement

Comment: use `use <db name>; <your sql statement>`. Append that statement so that it will first select the database and run the statement afterwards. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know *jenkins* so I hope the following makes sense. Sorry if it does not.

In order for INSERT to work, you must be connected to a database (i.e. one of its users). That user should contain LEAD_ACTV_CONFIG table, or it must be available to it (which means that some other user, who owns it, has granted the current user access privileges).

Now, if LEAD_ACTV_CONFIG is your own table, then your INSERT INTO would work properly; you don't need any additional privileges as you *own* the table so you can do *anything* with it.

If it is someone else's table, then either precede table name with owner name, such as `INSERT INTO littlefoot.lead_actv_config` (as if I own it), or create a synonym for that table in your schema:

```
create synonym lead_actv_config for littlefoot.lead_actv_config;
```

and access it just as you've posted in your question: `insert into lead_actv_config`

Comment: Thanks for your interest:) but my problem is different and I know about the sql statements. It just about the jenkins CI tool and I recommend to learn about it. It is useful tool.

Comment: Huh, that's what I was afraid of. I hope someone else will be able to assist.